# How to transform lines of code into a comment in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, comments

just wondering how to convert a set of code into comments, without having to go through each individual line of code and put a # at the beginning. Was thinking that maybe there was a quick way to highlight the code and then convert it into comment, atm i'm just cutting it off the code and then re-pasting it in later on.

Much appreciated :)

P.S. i m using Pycharm as my IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `jupyter notebook`, we select lines of code and press `ctrl and /` key simultaneously to convert a set of code into comments. Also same for vice versa.
You can try it in `Pycharm`.

Comment: tried it on pycharm but unfortunately that method (ctrl and /) doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the (""") symbol before and after the text you want to comment out. It is not exactly a comment and more of a text constant, but either way it is often used for documentation, so you can use it for multiline comments except for some cases when it causes unexpected errors
To avoid such cases you could simply use multiple single line comments by selecting the desired lines and using ctrl+/ to comment them out

Comment: Triple quotes are string literals, not comments. Not really good practice.
https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings